# Increasing Offset Y for Units and Numbers of ArcGIS Pro scale bar does nothing?

Tags: scale-bar, arcgis-pro

Using ArcGIS Pro 1.3.1 I have created a scale bar using the Scale Line 1 Metric template with a few modifications like:

- Show one division before zero
- Divisons: 11
- Subdivisions: 10
- Label Position: Below center
- Label: KILOMETRES

It appears as below:

[image]

How can I increase the gap between the scale bar line and the units (KILOMETRES) label (circled above)?

I thought that it might have been the Offset Y value (circled in red below) that might do it but that has no effect when I change it from 0 to 5 (as a test) and appears to be a bug.  I think it is a bug because altering Offset X moves the same label as expected.

[image]

The same bug appears to affect the positioning of the Numbers on the scale bar too.

The bug is still present in ArcGIS Pro 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using the right tool for the job. Try applying a **negative** offset value for the `Offset Y`; this should indeed move the label down. You can see that when entering the -10pt, the text in the preview panel to the down shows the text shifted down.

However, the scale bar label doesn't move down (I am on Pro 1.4). Sounds like a bug to me.

There are two options how this could be achieved:

1. Quick fix if you want to move the `Kilometers` label just a bit down. Choose another vertical alignment:

[image]

This will move the label down just a bit, but maybe it's good enough for you.

2. If you need to move the text in a more precise manner, use this  dirty hack.

a. Under the `Shadow` section, specify a negative value for the `Y Offset`. Choose the color of the text you'd like your labels to show with.

[image]

b. Under the `Appearance` section, choose for the label color `No color`.

[image]

The final scale bar would look like this:

[image]

Comment: Your shadow hack workaround works for both Units and Numbers - thanks!  It's a shame that its still broken in 2.0.  I don't suppose that there is a bug number that you can include in your post so that we can track when it is fixed?

Comment: Glad it works! I don't have a bug number yet, but I have informed the right people about this ;) will post any updates I'll get!

Comment: I just logged it with local support here too.

Answer (score 0):

I logged this with support in Australia and once they reproduced it locally, and it was also reproduced in Redlands a bug number was issued.

> The bug reference number is:
>
> **BUG-000107331**: In ArcGIS Pro, 'Offset -
>   Y' position setting under the Scale Bar - Units on 'Format Scale Line'
>   pane does not honored when scale bar 'Label Position' is set to 'Below
>   Center'.